# Proving ${0^n 1^n 2^n | n >= 0}$ is not regular

Tags: regular-expressions

This is not a homework assignment, but something I'm reviewing.

I need to prove that $0^n 1^n 2^n$ where $n \geq 0$ is not regular (Just the DFA, not related to CFG). I feel like this is similar to proving $0^n1^n$ is not regular because all you have to do is pump the 0's and then the size of each digit doesn't match so the language isn't regular.

But in [this solution](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/courses/cse396/content/hwSol-5.pdf) (page 3),
I understood only up to $xy = 0^k$. If I had continue from this, I would have said "If you have the string $xyyz$, then the string will have more $0$'s then $1$'s and $2$'s. The variable $y$ has to have at least one $0$ in it (because of the pumping lemma condition), so adding one more $y$ will add a $0$ breaking the language and reaching a contradiction. "

Is there anything wrong with my approach?

From the pdf, I see they then broke up the string into $x=0^a y= 0^b z=0^c 1^p 2^p$. Then by setting $i=0$, they show that $|y|$ will equal $0$ when it shouldn't because of the pumping lemma. I guess they wanted to show a pumped down version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a bit informal but basically correct: in this case you can pump in either direction and get a contradiction. It’s a good idea, though, to learn how to write it up more carefully, along the lines used in that PDF. You might write something like this, for instance:

> We have $xy=0^k$, where $1\le k\le p$. This means that $x=0^a$, $y=0^b$, and $z=0^c1^p2^p$ for some non-negative integers $a,b$, and $c$ such that $b>0$, $a+b=k$, and $a+b+c=p$. Now let $s'=xy^iz$; then $$s'=0^a(0^b)^i0^c1^p2^p=0^{a+bi+c}1^p2^p\;.$$ But $b>0$, so $a+bi+c=a+b+c=p$ if and only if $i=1$, i.e., $s'\in A_1$ if and only if $i=1$. This contradicts the conclusion of the pumping lemma and so shows that $A_1$ is not regular.

Or if you just wanted a more careful version of your argument, you could replace the last bit with this:

> Now let $s'=xy^2z$; then $$s'=0^a0^{2b}0^c1^p2^p=o^{a+2b+c}1^p2^p\;.$$ But $b>0$, so $a+2b+c>a+b+c=p$, and therefore $s'\notin A_1$. This contradicts the conclusion of the pumping lemma and so shows that $A_1$ is not regular.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to confirm I wasn't crazy. I know my proof was informal, but I was only trying to get my idea across and I'm glad it did.

Comment: @Matt: It did indeed. And I’d have been quite happy to get the informal proof when I was teaching this material.

Answer (score 0):

Homomorphisms preserve regularity. That means that if $h$ is a homomorphism and $L$ is a regular language then $h(L)$ is also regular. In your case you can take the homomorphism $h(0) = 0$, $h(1) = 1$, $h(2) = \epsilon$ which maps your language to the language $L' = \{ 0^n 1^n : n \geq 0 \}$, which you already know is not regular; if your language was regular, then so would $L'$ be, and this contradiction shows that your language is not regular.

---

What is a homomorphism? It is a mapping from $\Sigma$ to $\Sigma^*$. In other words, it is a mapping that maps each alphabet symbol to some word. For example, the homomorphism described above maps the symbols $0,1$ to themselves and $2$ to the empty word.

Given a homomorphism $h$, we can apply it to a word as follows $h(w_1\ldots w_n) = h(w_1)\ldots h(w_n)$. Here $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ are symbols forming the word $w_1\ldots w_n$. In words, we apply the homomorphism to each symbol, and concatenate the results.

Given a homomorphism $h$, we apply it to an entire language by applying it to each of the words in the language. For example,
$$h(\{0^n1^n2^n:n \geq 0\}) = \{h(0^n1^n2^n):n \geq 0\} = \{0^n1^n:n \geq 0\}.$$

If a language $L$ is regular and $h$ is a homomorphism then $h(L)$ is also regular. The easiest way to see that is by taking a regular expression for $L$ and applying the homomorphism to it. Therefore if $h(L)$ is not regular, $L$ also cannot be regular.

---

A related operation is *inverse homomorphism*. For a homomorphism $h$ and a language $L$, the language $h^{-1}(L)$ consists of all words $w$ such that $h(w) \in L$. If $L$ is regular then so is $h^{-1}(L)$. One way to see that is by taking an NFA for $L$ and replacing each edge labeled $\sigma$ by a path labeled $h(\sigma)$.